# django make a new model when another model gets added

Tags: python, django

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=8192)
    requirements = models.CharField(max_length=128, help_text='Memory: 16GB, Gpu: RTX 3090')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/thumbnails/')
    game = models.FileField(upload_to='media/games/')
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    downloads = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=48, null=True, default='Gaming')


    def create_preview(cls): # Here <------------------------
        preview = GamePreview.objects.create(title=cls.title, thumbnail=cls.thumbnail)
        preview.save()

class GamePreview(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True)
    downloads = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Basically I want to add a new preview that has the title, thumbnail... of the game that was created, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you store this in a separate model? You can use `Game` where you for example make certain fields `NULL`able.

Comment: If you really need a preview, I think you can work with a `OneToOneField` from the `Game` to the `GamePreview` and store a certain amount of data in the `GamePreview` object, such that this is not stored twice (both in the `Game` and `GamePreview`).

Comment: In the frontend, i have a homepage where I just want to show these 4 values, I'm storing it in a separate model so that when I send a request to the server it doesn't have to send ALL of the extra useless info that would take time, thanks for responding!

Comment: well then I think you can make a `GamePreview` class, and a `Game` with a `OneToOneField`. The `GamePreview` thus defines things like a thumbnail`, `downloads`, etc. and the `Game` should store the *rest* (things that do *not* appear in the `GamePreview`), this eliminates *duplicate data*, since this often is quite error-prone.

Comment: u can achieve this by changing just `cls` to `self`. That means `def create_preview(self):...`

Comment: and just to reduce number of columns you can just optimize your query by calling like this `Game.objects.all().values('id', 'title', 'thumbnail', 'downloads', 'comments')`

Comment: Or you can keep one model and add specific fields in serializer, which shall be returned in List/Detail API.